# Figuring out probability of two random events both happening

Tags: probability, statistics

So here's the problem:

The table below shows the distribution of education level attained by US residents based on data collected during the 2010 American Community Survey:

```
Highest level of education  %
Less than 9th Grade     0.10
9th to 12th  no diploma     0.09
High school grad - GED  0.25
Some college  No degree     0.23
Associate's degree  0.08
Bachelor's degree   --
Graduate or professional degree     0.09
```

Answer the following questions (give all answers to 2 decimal places):

a) Fill in the empty box for the proportion of US residents whose highest education level attained was a bachelors degree.

b) If two individuals are chosen at random from the population, what is the probability that both will have at least a bachelors degree?

c) If two individuals are chosen at random from the population, what is the probability that at least one will have some college or a college degree of some sort?

d) If two individuals are chosen at random from the population, what is the probability that exactly one will have some college or a college degree of some sort?

I managed to figure out a) which was 0.16. However, I tried a different methods to get b) but none of them worked. I answered .24, .25, and .01 but none of them were correct.

To answer b) I used the following formula:

P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A & B)
= (.16) + (.09) - (.16)(.09)

which gave me .24 but that was incorrect. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Is it just my browser, or have the questions all been truncated to be unusable? For me, (b),(c), and (d) all finish at "what is the probability that"!

Comment: In my browser I can scroll to the right to see the full questions.

Comment: @AdinaGoldberg Ah, thanks. I have to click on the area first, then scroll ..

Comment: @almagest It works fine in my browser as well and I'm on Firefox. The questions are just formatted with CTRL + K.

Answer (score 0):

When finding probability of two independent events, you can multiply the probability of the events.

Comment: For c) I figured out the answer to be .81 using the complement rule. For b) would the correct answer be (.25)^2 since you can't have a professional/graduate degree without a bachelors degree (0.16 + 0.09)?

Comment: I'd think that would be right.

Comment: What rule would I use to figure out d)? What does it mean when it says "that exactly one"

Comment: It means that you cannot have neither satisfying the condition, nor both.

Comment: @almagest What formula would I use to figure that out?

Comment: $P(A\ \mathrm{ XOR }\ B) = P(A\ \mathrm{ OR }\ B) - P(A\ \mathrm{ AND }\ B)$

-- XOR means exclusive or (i.e. one or the other but not both.)

Comment: @Jason The prob for an individual satisfying the condition in (d) is 0.23 + 0.08 + 0.16 + 0.09 = 0.56 (assuming an Associate's degree counts as a College degree, I have no idea how the US system works). So the prob that neither of two individuals satisfies the condition is 0.44^2, the prob that both do is 0.56^2 and hence the prob that just one does is 1-0.44^2-0.56^2.

Comment: @almagest Awesome explanation, thank you so much!!!!!!!!